# How to handle parsing hundreds files in R?

Tags: r

I want to parse last year weather data which are recorded in CSV files. Each CSV file includes one day of data. So I have 365 CSV files need to parse. What is the best way to handle these files? As far as I know, I need to load all of them into R and bind them into one big data frame. But I don't know whether this is the best solution. What if I have more than one years of data files? Do I need to load all of them into memory? Or is there any other way to handle them?

Each file is about 1M to 1.5M.

Comment: How big is each file?  If there are lots of files and memory is an issue, try with `RevoScaleR` using `rxImport`

Comment: Is a SQL Database a solution?

Comment: Each file is about 1M to 1.5M.

Comment: I don't want to use SQL database. Just using R to load them and analysis.

Comment: Each file is small. I would just make all data one data.table.

Comment: Use the list.files() function. This function produce a character vector of the names of files or directories in the named directory. Then iterate through the vector using a for loop, read the files and rbind() them into a big data file. Whether you'll need all of them depends on what you want to do. You may do some feature extraction or preprocessing on the fly already.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to get all your files to read using `list.files`, read them into a list of data frames, then rbind all the frames together:

```
#setwd('dirwithallmycsvs')

x <- list.files(pattern = '.+\\.csv$')

out = lapply(x, read.csv)

out2 = do.call(rbind, out)
```

Your output should now be one dataframe. You will need to take care all the columns are the same across your files.

Comment: To speed it up, you can use `library(data.table); out = rbindlist(lapply(x, fread))`